# Three tables with some matching data and some not - want to data from all three

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have three tables

Costs (47 rows)
Budgets (60 rows)
Committed Costs (12 rows)

All three have the same 2 fields and than a number
JobNumber, CostCode, (either costs, budget, commitedcosts)

They all have the same JobNumber and they all CostCode in common.  However they also each have unique CostCodes.  I need to run a query that would get me results from all three tables like this:

JobNumber, CostCode, Costs, Budgets, CommitedCosts

Currently I am using outer joins on the three tables and only getting 47 results since the Costs table is the first table selected from.

Comment: What type of outer join are you using?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your schema (3 tables) + some sample data and your desired result (here).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm completely following but maybe this is what you are looking for?

I'm taking all three tables and then using UNION ALL (combine but don't remove duplicate records) to convert them into a single table, placing NULL's in the columns that are not shared. Then I'm taking that consolidated table and grouping on your two common columns (JobNumber, CostCode). I'm not sure what kind of data you're looking to get out of the other three columns...are you looking for the COUNT of records from each table for that JobNumber+CostCode? Or maybe the SUM?

So this sample query, will give you a unique list of JobNumber+Costcode, and the Sum of Costs, Budgets and CommitedCosts for each one:

```
SELECT x.JobNumber, x.CostCode
    , Costs = SUM(x.Costs)
    , Budgets = SUM(x.Budgets)
    , CommitedCosts = SUM(x.CommitedCosts)
FROM (
    SELECT JobNumber, CostCode
        , Costs
        , Budgets = NULL
        , CommitedCosts = NULL
    FROM Costs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT JobNumber, CostCode
        , Costs = NULL
        , Budgets
        , CommitedCosts = NULL
    FROM Budgets
    UNION ALL
    SELECT JobNumber, CostCode
        , Costs = NULL
        , Budgets = NULL
        , CommitedCosts
    FROM CommitedCosts
) x
GROUP BY x.JobNumber, x.CostCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you might have your answered.

if you have multiple entry in same table then you need enter sum of cost i below query to get actual value.

```
 Select a.*,b.Costs,c.Budgets,d.CommitedCosts
from 
(Select distinct JobNumber, CostCode from Costs
union
Select distinct JobNumber, CostCode from Costs
union
Select distinct JobNumber, CostCode from Costs)a
left outer join
(Select * from Costs)b
on a.JobNumber=b.JobNumber and a.CostCode =b.CostCode
left outer join
(Select * from Costs)c
on a.JobNumber=c.JobNumber and a.CostCode =c.CostCode
left outer join
(Select * from Costs)d
on a.JobNumber=d.JobNumber and a.CostCode =d.CostCode
```